# System calls and Commands

Tags: windows, winapi, system-calls

How would you make system calls in a c++ program for windows, as the system() method allows for system commands, also what's the difference between the two?

EDIT: I mean difference between system calls  and system commands

EDIT: I have found that system commands are commands that you can run in cmd, you can also call these through the system() method, but I still don't know how to make system calls

Comment: "System calls" has a pretty well defined meaning in operating system design.  It has nothing to do with system().  Nor does Windows expose the functionality at all, you work with the Win32 API layer in a user mode program.  This may (or may not) eventually result in a ring transition.  The native Windows API is undocumented, allowing Microsoft to innovate Windows versions without much fear of breaking existing code.

Comment: In the MS Windows world, the Win32 API are functions you call that ultimately make system calls. System calls execute  kernel code.

Unix(s) does the same thing with the POSIX library but most functions in POSIX have the same name as system call names.

For example, if you were to call open() from a c program, the libc implementation would be called and then call the system call open().

System calls require a special assembly instruction to switch from user-mode to kernel-mode

Comment: @Hans I knew what system calls were but you explanation was usefull I do now Understand the difference between the systemcalls and commands, but I have found that by using the ntdll.dll file I should be able to make system calls,I am just unable to find parameters that satisfy these functions, at  [link]http://dev.metasploit.com/users/opcode/syscalls.html you can find windows system calls, I can access them through the dll but I don't have an idea of what half the parameters are,this is a coding project for an operating systems course I need to call 5 windows sytem calls and then later 5 linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic question.  Find a tutorial online or a book.  Also, MSDN has documentation on most of the Win32 functions.

```
#include <windows.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Hello, World", "My First Win32 Call", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is not at all a basic question, I have written well over 50 c++ programs that have been millions of times more complex than you example, you example doesn't even directly use system calls or system commands

Comment: okay then how about `asm int 3`.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No not really, I am not allowed to use assembly I need to use c++, please read comment above about ntdll.dll, it will explain more about what I am looking for

Comment: I doubt you’re going to find any documentation about this from Microsoft.  I think what you are asking is for a list of software interrupts implemented by the OS.  I would suggest disassembling one of the system DLLs like kernel32.dll to find out how to prepare the stack and registers.  By the way, it isn’t a C++ question unless I still don’t understand what you’re asking.

Comment: well what I am trying to accomplish is to make a system call with c++ in windows, I am able to make system calls in linux but it is much easier, this is an assignment for an operating sytems design course I am taking, The link I posted in the previous comment that went to hans passant is a list of windows systems calls, I can now call these system calls through the ntdll.dll but I would like some help as what to pass to any of these functions, I would just like to be able to call any one of them, Thank you

Comment: If you give an example written for Linux, then I will give the equivalent written for Windows.

Comment: `val1 = syscall(SYS_getpid);`

Comment: I don't think `syscall` is what you want.  How do you pass parameters?  The parameters need to be on the stack and/or in the registers.  How do you tell `syscall` to set this correctly?  No one writes code like this.  Programs are written against an API.  The system functions have a published calling convention so programs know how to call it.  These system functions are written in assembly with possibly some C or C++ code.  You cannot write this entirely in C or C++.

Comment: Yeah could have guessed that programs aren't written like this, that is why no one was able to help me. I handed in the assignment today. Thanks for your help, An Admin can delete this question as it serves no purpose without an answer, unless someone wants to further investigate ntdll.dll, but I'm over it.

Comment: What did you turn in if you couldn't find an answer?

Comment: I used a bunch of system commands, luckily the windows part was only 33%, 33% was linux commands, and then 33% was based on minux's design

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the difference between calling a system function such as CopyFile through the Win API vs calling copy through system(), then by using the system function you can either statically or dynamically call the code that copies the file. By calling system() it spawns a separate process which calls the executable called copy and passes it parameters to copy the file.